# Is there a way to prevent GCC from converting unsigned int to signed?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

I am novice embedded developer. I am developing for SH7058 CPU. I have the following code (it's simplified, but the point remains):

**EDIT**

I made a typo. The right code is

```
#define FLAG (0x40)
#define ADDRESS (0xFFFFB000u)
#define P ((volatile unsigned char *)ADDRESS)

unsigned char some_func(){
    return *P & FLAG;
}
```

And corresponding assembly output is

```
some_func():
        mov.w   .L3,r1
        mov.b   @r1,r0
        rts     
        and     #64,r0
.L3:
        .short  -20480
```

And unsigned long `0xFFFFB000` turns to signed short `-20480`. Older versions of GCC give similar results.

Is there a way to tell GCC not to convert unsigned to signed? Convertion of `#define` to variable is not suitable.

Comment: is `&&` intentional? do you mean `&`?

Comment: `&& (0x40)` doesn't make much sense, it's always true so only the left side would matter. I suspect it should be `&` also.

Comment: It doesn't matter if signed or unsigned encoding is used. Both `-20480` and `0xfffb000` will map to the same 16-bit-long pattern.

Comment: I am sorry, `&&` is a typo. @tstanisl I want compiler to produce `mov.l` instruction but it produces `mov.w`. I'm not sure how it will work on a real hardware.

Comment: I guess that CPU will sign expand the value of `0xB000` to `0xFFFFB0000` when loading a register from memory. This optimization saves you  2 bytes.

Comment: @tstanisl Yes, that is so. But I want to be sure that when I flash my ROM I won't brick ECU. I tested on emulator and it runs as expected. But I who knows how it will run on real hardware. So I want to be sure to be safe.

Comment: You should probably remove the erroneous code to clarify the question.  Unfortunately there is already an answer, given in good faith and up-voted, based on the original code which would be rendered nonsense if you did that.  However that answer does not currently answer your intended question I think, even though the guess at the correction was spot on.  May have been better to delete the question and start again.

Comment: You are going to make very slow progress is you choose to second guess the compiler's code translation. - trust the tool or use a tool you do trust  Occam's razor applies; GCC is a tool used to build billions of lines of code used in mission critical systems world-wide, you should trust it to translate your code faithfully - especially for trivially simple code such as this - if it could not get that right, nothing much world work.

Comment: @Clifford I ain't gonna trust GCC becasue I got code that GCC 4.7 translates to thing that does no pass unit tests. And the same code compiled by GCC 12.2 surprisingly passes unit tests.

Comment: @alex That kind of change in behaviour is normally a result of _undefined_ or _implementation defined_ behaviour in _your code_.  Have you ever put that code through a static analyser such as Lint or set the  `-Wall -Werror` and even `-Wpedantic` flags and cleared all warnings?  Also often building with aggressive optimisation can sometimes spot bugs that regular compilation ignores such as use of uninitialised variables.  Either way I'd suspect your code quality before GCC's translation.

Comment: @alex   In this case you have simply failed to understand what the compiler has done, so are hardly equipped to check the compiler's work.  If you have less trivial code and apply optimisation you will really struggle to understand what it has generated.

Comment: Regarding "_Either way I'd suspect your code quality before GCC's translation._" - that was not meant to sound disparaging about your code - if it were my code, I'd still suspect error on my part before I went down the compiler code generation rabbit hole.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you for your comments. I am not so new to programming in general, so I understand very well what you are talking about. By the way, I use PVS Studio to do static analysis of my projects. And do testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry too much about how the compiler generates code or how the code is *presented* in the disassembly.  It will produce the same result.

The interesting thing here is not the signed/unsigned thing but rather that it shortened the literal.  For the short to load into a 32-bit register, and set the upper 16 bits to 0xFFFF, the short must be considered as signed.

It is the compiler being rather clever, the short integer 0xB000 when interpreted as a signed value and loaded into a 32-bit register becomes 0xFFFFB000 as required, but if it were unsigned 0xB000u, it would become 0x0000B000.

What the compiler has done is to use a "trick" to allow a trivial code-size optimisation.  If you were to change the address to say 0xFFFF3000, the full 32 bits would be stored because the "sign-extension" trick would not result in 0xFFFF in the upper 16 bits:

Changing to:

```
#define ADDRESS (0xFFFF3000u)
```

results in:

```
some_func():
  mov.l .L4,r1
  mov.b @r1,r0
  rts 
  and #64,r0
.L4:
  .long -53248
```

Note the literal is now `long`.  It is still presented as *signed* because at the assembler level, there really is no difference, it is the same bit pattern, and the same code regardless of the *presentation* in the disassembly. Signedness is a matter of interpretation (how the bit pattern is used) and presentation (how it is displayed), it makes no difference at the machine-level.

For example, let's say we had a hypothetical 4 bit machine, where 0xF would represent either -1 (two's complement) or 15 depending on whether it was signed or unsigned.  Then lets say we have two operations one signed

```
-1 - 1 = -2
```

and another

```
15 - 1 = 14
```

both expressions are the same machine operation

```
0xF - 0x1 = 0xE
```

So the *presentation* in the disassembly as signed is an irrelevance, it is the same code regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The code is nonsensical and buggy and therefore the machine code will follow suit, although I don't think this machine code here was generated by the posted C code(?).

- `*P && FLAG` This is nonsense and equivalent to `*P != 0`, and will return 1 or 0. You likely meant `&`.
- `((unsigned char *)ADDRESS)` This must be `volatile unsigned char*`.
- `(0x40)` The parenthesis here is pointless at best and problematic at worst. In case you wish to use these constants as part of various pre-processor tricks, then integer constants shouldn't be surrounded by parenthesis. If you use the style `(1u << 6)` then that's another story.

Corrected and cleaned up code:

```
#define FLAG    0x40u
#define ADDRESS 0xFFFFB000u
#define P ((volatile unsigned char*)ADDRESS)

unsigned char some_func (void) {
    return *P & FLAG;
}
```

Also in professional embedded systems, make it a habit of using `stdint.h` instead of the primitive data types.

As for what "magic numbers" that show up in a certain disassebly, they might have weird formats such as decimal or signed - it won't matter there. You'll have to go even further down than disassembly, into the raw binary OP codes and there signs do not exist.

Comment: `volatile` access is a good idea in general for embedded apps, yet I do not see the strong need for it here  in this function to read a byte.  Please expand on "This must be `volatile unsigned char*`".

Comment: @Lundin I am sorry, `&&` is a typo. You say that in binary OP codes signs do not exist. That's true, but as you can see, compiler produce `mov.w` instruction, and I want it to produce `mov.l` instruction

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Because this is blatantly obviously a memory mapped hardware register. The SH family maps them starting with 0xFFFF.

Comment: @alex Correct the code, compile with optimizations enabled then try again?

Comment: @Lundin I compiled code you provided using godbolt. No changes. `0xFFFFB000u` still turns to `-20480`. I think something is going on in GCC's RTL.

Comment: @alex Why is -20480 a problem?  It does not look like one as it is the same  pattern as 0xFFFFB000 as 16 (truncated) or 32-bit.

Comment: @alex I'm not making any sense out of your posted assembler regardless of that constant. `rts` meaning return from subroutine so it returns non-conditionally before bit masking...?

Comment: @chux-Reinstate Monica I want compiler to produce `mov.l` instruction and to load full register but it produces `mov.w` and loads half of register (but it is sign extended as said in CPU manual). And then it accesses memory by this address. I'm not sure how it will work on a real hardware.

Comment: @Lundin It's so called delayed branch. It starts returning, executes the next instruction and then actually returns.

Comment: @alex Ok so I picked up the SH core manual and peeked. It would seem that `MOV.W` comes with built in sign extension? If so then you don't need a slower 32 bit register access if it just means filling up the address with 0xFFFF. It can shave off some bytes of executable size this way, even if it won't affect speed. Meaning you _could_ probably do `(volatile unsigned char* volatile)` and force a 32 bit access but all you achieve with that is a bigger and/or slower program.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, `mov.w` is sign extended, it is explicitly stated in the manual. Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm answering my own question. This is not quite what I needed, but it's very close. This trick can be used:

```
#define FLAG 0x40
#define ADDRESS "0xFFFFB000"
extern unsigned char P asm(ADDRESS);

unsigned char some_func(){
    return P & FLAG;
}
```

Here is assembly output:

```
_some_func:
        mov.l   .L2,r1
        mov.b   @r1,r0
        rts     
        and     #64,r0
.L2:
        .long   0xFFFFB000
```

This trick is based on specifying assembly variable name as described in section 6.47.4 of the GCC manual:

> You can specify the name to be used in the assembler code for a C function or variable by writing the asm keyword after the declarator.

But it turns out that GCC passes a string you specify in parentheses to assembler as is. So, because address is valid input for assembler, one can specify an address for a variable.